# Issue with <%: ... %> vs. <%= %> when displaying generated text

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am writing an MVC application with C#. In this one particular section, I have a conditional switch for the navigation to highlight the appropriate tab.  Here is the code for that:

```
<script type="text/C#" runat="server">
    string oController;
    string oAction;
    const string current = "class=\"current_page\"";

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        oController = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
        oAction = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();

        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
</script>

<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li <%= (oController.Equals("Home") ? current : "") %>><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/CustomerManager/">Customer Manager</a></li>
        <!-- <%: oController.Equals("Home") %> -->
        <!-- <%: oAction %> -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

On this line (**`<li <%= (oController.Equals("Home") ? current : "") %>><a href="/">Home</a></li>`**) if I use the `<%: %>` ASP nugget instead of `<%= %>` (as is recommended, since the latter is being phased out soon), the generated text comes out as

```
<li class=&quot;current_page&quot;><a href="/">Home</a></li>
```

Instead of

```
<li class="current_page"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
```

Any suggestions and/or reasons why this is happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `<%:` is intended to *encode* data such as user input. In your case, that is self-generated (trusted) html, so you don't **want** to encode it; `<%=` is the correct usage.

`<%:` is for things like `<%:user.Name%>`, which conveniently prevents issues for malicious text with xss etc in it.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  I read on one of the ASP.NET MVC official tutorial that `<%=` is being removed after version 4. Do you know if this is true or not?

Comment: @Anders - I haven't heard that, but I would find it very unlikely. For starters, it would break too much code.

Comment: `<%=` is completely necessary sometimes. use `<%:` at all times unless you have a good reason not to (like yours). It isn't being phased out

Comment: Thank you both for the clarity, I did think it was odd that they would try to phase out a tag.

Answer (score 0):

You could just have the class be empty when the value is not `Home`.  Clearly you are trying to omit it all together, but it would be a solution none the less.

```
const string current = "current_page";
<li class="<%: (oController.Equals("Home") ? current : "") %>"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
```

Comment: The only issue with this is if the page is not selected there is no css class applied. An empty class tag seems inappropriate to me.